# Android ddms screen capture with skin?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can we use DDMS to take a screen capture with a device skin? Right now I'm just getting the exact screen rect area in my screen captures,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think DDMS tool has any such option; 
it captures only the display: the screen area(therefore the name screen capture).

Comment: Exactly. DDMS works with a real device or an emulator; it can't know which it's running on. Drawing the skin is entirely handled by the emulator process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, assuming you have an emulator open with the skin you want, ensure that you have focus on the emulator. Press Alt-PrtScn to screen capture just the focused window, open up MS Paint and past the clipboard contents, you will have the screen shot + skin + window frame. It's up to you to crop that out.